# Vertical centering a block heading

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a simple flex-based table.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

h2, ul {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
  
h2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

ul {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Heading</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li>baz</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

First of all, contrary to what is displayed in my local project, the `h2` and `ul` children do not take 100% of the section's height in the snippet. Why?

The main problem: I'd like the `h2` block to fill the `section`'s and its text vertically centered. My aim is to change the `background-color` of the left and right cell separately. I set the `vertical-align` option but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: _"the h2 and ul children do not take 100% of the section's height in the snippet. Why?"_ - because they have different margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will have to use `display: flex` on `h2` and then set `align-items: center`, and `justify-content: flex-end` if you want right text align. Also you can remove margins to make items same height.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
h2,
ul {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: white;
}
ul {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Heading</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li>baz</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flex align (-items, -self) for vertical align

```css
section {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

h2, ul {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
  text-align: right;
  align-self: center;
}
  
h2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

ul {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Heading</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li>baz</li>
    <li>baz</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: I want the blue block to have the same height as the yellow one.

Answer (score 0):

need to define line height

line-height: 100px;  or whatever in you need in h2